# How to solve this statement?

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

How to solve this equation by removing one element? (one element is one spatially finished item.)
[image]

hint :

> also valid considering
>
>  [image]

Comment: Well, I suggest we Remote the equation, since the empati statement is true, I consider it solved

Comment: **Question seems like vague or not correct**. Are you asking to make a true statement by removing one element ? then change the title ... Or are you asking to make an equation by removing one element, which can be solved ? then, change the question to indicate that we should get an equation with atleast one unknown (like x) which can then be solved ...

Comment: @qqjkztd , thanks ! Might be better to remove that word "equation" from the body also !

Comment: I know that when you say "one element is one spatially finished item" you think you're making things more clear, but you're not.

Answer (score 16):

You'll note that there are a lot of similarities between

> The shape of the 8 and the shape of the 3.

If we

> Take away the parts of the 8 that are also on the 3, we're left with a 7. This is more clearly shown graphically below. A red 3 is placed over a blue 8, and the area left is a 7: [image]

So what the equation is saying is that

> If we visually take a 3-shaped curve out of the 8-shape, we're left with a 7.

Comment: That's clever! How about the hint though? I don't think it works for that.

Comment: In regards to the hint... if we XOR the 8 and the 3, the overlap cancels and you're left with a 7.

Comment: Well spotted. I think you are on the right track but the question is "How to solve this equation by removing one element?". However you didn't remove anything since you state that the equation is already solved.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more serious attempt.

Subtraction:

> [image]
>  You can just about make out $10 - 3 = 7$. The connected-element removed is the 'v' in the top loop of the '8'.

Addition:

> [image]
>  It says $4 + 3 = 7$. The connected-element removed is the bottom of the '8'.

Answer (score 3):

> The trick answer (cf 'lateral thinking' tag) is to remove the element of *equality*. This works for both equations.
>
>  Admittedly, it does nothing for the 'visual' tag, other than that the element of equality covers the whole *spatially finished* equation in each case.
>
>  :P

Comment: This was my first thought too =)

Comment: I also thought about that but it doesn't become an "equation" in this case.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed This was always intended as a cheeky answer. The core idea was to remove a *conceptual* element (not the ‘equals’ sign). If a more literal sense is required, you might consider it to be the removal of the whole equation. Problem ‘solved’. :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

> [image: Element removal]

Maybe a bit too solved, there...

Answer (score 1):

Question is very vague and I have asked OP to clarify in a comment to the question.

Meanwhile, I think to solve an "equation" we require an "unknown".
Here, the 7 is not a 7, rather it is part of a question mark "?" which is the "unknown" in the "equation" and hence 8-3=? is 8-3=5.
Similarly 8+3=? is 8+3=11.

Answer (score 0):

> [image]
>
>  Remove the 3 and flip it `L = -8`

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind my paint skills.

> I copied the 7 from the right and made the pixels red to make it clear.
>  If you Move the 7 from the right inside the 3 on the left, it does perfectly align to be exact as the 8. Which makes the equation "8 - 8 = 0"
>  [image]

Comment: Gung nafjre vf qvfgenpgvat gur 3 sebz 8.(rot13) Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see the equation:

> Remove $-$ sign from $8 - 3 = 7 $, and add the slant line on $=$ sign:
>  $$ 83 \neq 7$$

It works with $ 8 + 3 = 7 $ also.